# SpringCloudStream - how to create delayed exchange?

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq

I want to create delayed exchange from [rabbitMQ plugin](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange).

At first I tried to use spring binders as I can see, that `delayed-exchange` flag is available:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:              
      bindings:
        delayed-ex:
          group: update-delayed
          contentType: application/json
          consumer:
            max-attempts: 1
      rabbit:
        bindings:
          delayed-ex:
            consumer:
              transacted: true
              auto-bind-dlq: true
              republish-to-dlq: true
              delayed-exchange: true
              requeue-rejected: false
```

Unfortunately, this config is creating me simple `topic` exchange without any flags.

I can create bean with:

```
@Bean
public CustomExchange delayedExchange() {
    final Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<>();
    args.put("x-delayed-type", "topic");     
    return new CustomExchange("delayed-ex", "x-delayed-message", true, false, args);
}
```

And it is working with current config, but it is giving me stacktraces about existing exchanges which I want to override:

> Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'type' for exchange 'delayed-ex' in vhost '/': received 'topic' but current is ''x-delayed-message'', class-id=40, method-id=10)

Another thing (don't know if it is a problem) I want to have consumer and producer in the same service, just for having buffer for my messages.

Also, I checked source of `delayed-exchange` flag, and saw that this flag is doing absolutely nothing (Am I wrong?), because `isDelayed` methods from `AbstractExchange` is not called.

Is it possible to declare delayed exchange with type `x-delayed-message` and do it by configuration, instead of declaring bean? Also I want to remove that stacktraces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with wrong version of `spring-rabbit` dependency. I used `1.5.6.RELEASE` which do not use `isDelayed()` method. Changing it into `1.7.3.RELEASE` version fix the problem.

I deleted my custom bean and create this config:

```
spring  
  cloud:
    stream:              
      bindings:
        delayed-ex:
          group: update-delayed
          contentType: application/json
          consumer:
            max-attempts: 1
      rabbit:
        bindings:
          delayed-ex:
            consumer:
              transacted: true
              auto-bind-dlq: true
              republish-to-dlq: true
              delayed-exchange: true
              requeue-rejected: false     
            producer:
              delayed-exchange: true
```

Now, exchange and queues are created automatically by config without any stacktraces.